# Is order of calls within a constructor guaranteed

Tags: constructor, kotlin

Suppose I have a Kotlin (data) class with the primary constructor and a secondary one which fills vals/vars of the primary one with calling some methods (see the example). My question is whether the order in which these methods are being called is guaranteed, i.e. whether in my example `checkConsitency` would **always** get called before `extractNames`.

```
data class LawAndOrder(val sherifs: Int, val names: List<String>) {
    constructor(westerners: List<Westerner>) :
            this(sherifs = westerners.checkConsistency(),
                 names = westerners.extractNames())
}

data class Westerner(val name: String) {
    val isCriminal: Boolean
        get() = name == "Jesse James"
}

private fun List<Westerner>.checkConsistency(): Int {
    println("Checking consistency")
    if (isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Crime and chaos")
    if (any { it.isCriminal }) throw IllegalArgumentException("Inadmissible")
    return size
}

private fun List<Westerner>.extractNames(): List<String> {
    println("Extracting names")
    return map { it.name }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val westerners = listOf(Westerner("John Wayne"), Westerner("Limonádový Joe"))
    val lawAndOrder = LawAndOrder(westerners)
    println(lawAndOrder)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Kotlin Language Specification](https://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/#_order_of_evaluation) has this to say about it (emphasis mine):

> 16.39. Order of Evaluation
>   Generally, the order of evaluation is left to right, non-lazy (eager). Some expressions have special rules for order of evaluation of their constituent parts (some of them may be not evaluated at all). **Order of evaluation of named arguments corresponds to their order at the invocation site, not the declaration site.**
>
> TODO